# How to C# linq GroupBy multiple arrays with array values

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have an array of objects "Channel" Which each have properties

```
string axis

//times and values correspond to each other. Their lengths will always be the same. times[0] value is values[0], etc...   
float[] times
float[] values
```

Lets say there are 3 channels in the channels array, and their float[] "times" values are...

```
channel[0].times = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
channel[1].times = 0, 2, 2.5, 3, 5, 6
channel[2].times = 1, 2.5, 3, 4, 5.5, 6
```

MiniChannel object has properties

```
string axis
float value;
```

The result I am looking for is something like this...

```
Dictionary<float, MiniChannel[]> MatchingTimes;
//float corresponds to the times value
```

MatchingTimes[0] contains...

```
new MiniChannel0
MiniChannel.axis = channel[1].axis
MiniChannel.value= channel[1].values[0]
```

MatchingTimes[1] contains...

```
new MiniChannel0
MiniChannel.axis = channel[0].axis
MiniChannel.value= channel[0].values[0]

new MiniChannel1
MiniChannel.axis = channel[2].axis
MiniChannel.value = channel[2].values[0]
```

.....

MatchingTimes[5.5] contains...

```
new MiniChannel0
MiniChannel.axis = channel[2].axis
MiniChannel.value= channel[2].values[4]
```

etc... etc... for each time value.

So I am trying to group all channels with the same time and get their value for that time as well as their string axis.

Ive looked around for answers in regards to the groupby linq method, but I only saw people dealing with either a single array, or an array with multiple elements, but still only 1 item from each element.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
IDictionary<float, MiniChannel[]> matchingTimes = channel
    .SelectMany(c => c.times.Select((t, i) => new KeyValuePair<float, MiniChannel>(t, new MiniChannel {axis = c.axis, value = c.values[i]})))
    .GroupBy(t => t.Key)
    .ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Select(c => c.Value).ToArray());
```

Comment: I didn't get to trying this since It used Tuple, which the version of C# I am using doesn't support (scripting for unity engine). Nachos answer seemed to work though.

Comment: You may replace `Tuple` with any class (`KeyValuePair` is also suitable for example). I've updated my answer.

Comment: kk, I think all is good with this answer. Will post back later if there is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly... this is a possible solution

EDITED:

```
Dictionary<float, MiniChannel[]> MatchingTimes = channel
          .SelectMany(c => c.times)
          .Distinct()
          .ToDictionary(k => k, v => channel
                        .Where(c => c.times.Contains(v))
                        .Select(c => new MiniChannel {
                            axis = c.axis,
                            value = c.values[Array.IndexOf(c.times, v)]
                        })
          .ToArray());
```

Comment: I have not fully tested, but this seems to do exactly what I want. Thank you! If I run into problems I'll unmark it as the answer.

Comment: In your result `value` is always equal `times` (or dictionary key), while it suppose to be `values` array element

Comment: Yes I just noticed that and was about to unmark this as answer. I didn't notice this was returning just the time. The value needs to be the actual values from the values array.

Comment: Ops... I edited the answer and I think it works now.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can make out: (by the way... you nowhere assigned the times array... so I took `times` instead of `values`)

a basic setup of your values:

```
public class MiniChannel
{
    public string Axis { get; set; }
    public float Value { get; set; }
}

public class Channel
{
    public string Axis { get; set; }
    public float[] Times { get; set; }
    public float[] Values { get; set; }
}
```

and the queries:

```
Channel[] channels = new Channel[3];

channels[0] = new Channel
{
    Axis = "channel1",
    Times = new[] { 1f, 2f, 3f, 4f, 5f, 6f }
};

channels[1] = new Channel
{
    Axis = "channel1",
    Times = new[] { 0f, 2f, 2.5f, 3f, 5f, 6f }
};

channels[2] = new Channel
{
    Axis = "channel1",
    Times = new[] { 1f, 2.5f, 3f, 4f, 5.5f, 6f }
};

MiniChannel miniChannel0 = new MiniChannel {Axis = channels[0].Axis, Value = channels[0].Times[0]};
MiniChannel miniChannel1 = new MiniChannel {Axis = channels[1].Axis, Value = channels[1].Times[0]};
MiniChannel miniChannel2 = new MiniChannel {Axis = channels[2].Axis, Value = channels[2].Times[0]};

List<MiniChannel> list = new List<MiniChannel>
{
    miniChannel0, miniChannel1, miniChannel2
};

var result = from minichannel in list
    group minichannel by minichannel.Value
    into g
    select new {Value = g.Key, Items = g};

Dictionary<float, MiniChannel[]> dict = result.ToDictionary(key => key.Value, value => value.Items.Select(x => x).ToArray());
```

Comment: I think some of the things I wrote in my question may have confused you (I wasn't to clear with my examples). Check Krzysztof answer to see an example of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer selected, I was able to make this...

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static partial class ExtHelper
{
    public static Dictionary<T, W[]> GroupEqualsInObjects<T, U, W>(this U[] items, Func<U, T[]> funcVariables, Func<U, int, W> funcValues)
    {
        Dictionary<T, W[]> MatchingItems = items
        .SelectMany(c => funcVariables(c)
        .Select((t, i) => new {key = t, item = funcValues(c, i)})
        .ToDictionary(x => x.key, y => y.item))
        .GroupBy(t => t.Key)
        .ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Select(c => c.Value).ToArray());

        return MatchingItems;
    }
}
```

which can be used like this...

```
Dictionary<float, MiniChannel[]> MatchingTimes = channels.GroupEqualsInObjects<float, ChannelObject, MiniChannelObject>(c => c.times, (c, i) => new MiniChannel{axis = c.axis, value = c.values[i]});
```

You might not need to specifically declare the generics float, ChannelObject, and MiniChannelObject, as it showed no red lines when I removed them, but since I am working in the unity game engine, which runs on a lower version of c#, it was giving me errors.